Do airlines serve meal even sometimes when the fasten seat belt sign had been switched on?
I read:

Singapore Airlines Pilots Turned On Seatbelt Sign During Turbulence [...] The report states that at this point, the CVR record shows “a pilot called out that the fasten seat belt sign had been switched on.” However, passengers onboard the aircraft who have shared their experience have not noted the seatbelt light was on and cabin crew continued with their meal service. This discrepancy will likely be part of the ongoing TSIB investigation, and further analysis of the incident is being conducted to understand all contributing factors.

I'm trying to understand why "cabin crew continued with their meal service" seems to be part of the claimed discrepancy. Do airlines serve  meal even sometimes when the fasten seat belt sign had been switched on? I thought they did (which would me it is not part of the claimed discrepancy), but the above confuses me.

The discrepancy is a discrepancy between a sign indicating potential turbulence and the fact that cabin crew are going around a lot of unsecured items. The fact that they sometime do it doesn't mean there is no discrepancy.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question about travel but a (possibly bad faith) language question.

@Relaxed,. thanks, Do airlines serve meal even sometimes when the fasten seat belt sign had been switched on?

That's what the article implies and what you yourself wrote (“I thought they did”). Is that even a (good faith) question?

@Relaxed better phrasing (sorry, thought it was obvious): Do regulations and/or airline policies allow airline staff to serve meal even sometimes when the fasten seat belt sign had been switched on?

The quote says the seatbelt light was not in fact on, so what exactly are you asking?

@FranckDernoncourt That's a more reasonable question but you might as well start from scratch, scrap the quote and faulty reasoning in the current question, and ask on aviation.SE rather than here. Do check if it hasn't been asked before.

Then again, is it even a question? You said they did serve meals when the seatbelt sign is on, the article said they did in this case, and Singapore Airlines announced they want to change that in the future (again implying it wasn't part of their policies until now).

From personal experience, it is certainly very common on the major US airlines, but I've heard that it's not at other places. Is your question specifically about Singapore Airlines?

@NateEldredge thanks, any airline

First, note that the record shows the sign was turned on at 7:49:32 UTC, just after the initial (mild) turbulence started, at 7:49:21.
The main event which resulted in passengers “becoming airborne” started at 7:49:40, less than 8 seconds later, and they then fell back down within the next 4 seconds.
So, no, the seatbelt sign was not turned on before the turbulence, and there were only 8 seconds between the sign being turned on and the lethal event.
Many people would not have noticed the sign being turned on: most only notice when the cabin crew makes an announcement or even when the crew goes around the cabin to check every one is buckled in, and there wouldn’t have been enough time to stop service, stow the carts, or have the cabin crew return to their own seats. There wasn’t even enough time for cabin crew to get to the intercom to make the announcement!
Next, in my experience there are different levels in the handling of turbulence in the cabin:

You can have the seat belt sign turned on, but crew still serving meals
Ditto, but there are restrictions on the leak service (e.g. no hot drinks)
The next level is that they stop (or don’t start) service
The next one is that cabin crew are ordered back to their seats and to strap in.

The different levels and their details may depend on the airline operating rules (so it’s quite possible the first level exists at some airlines and not others), and the choice of the level is up to the cockpit crew, depending on their assessment of the severity of the turbulence.
If the cockpit crew had expected the turbulence to have that magnitude, they would have immediately ordered cabin crew to stop service and return to their seats, but even that would probably have been too late.
So no discrepancy at all, the big questions which remain are whether it could have been possible to predict the event a bit earlier, either with the existing tools on board, or with new systems, and how to go forward to avoid such incidents in the future, whether we can predict that turbulence or not.
Obviously it would be better if it was possible to predict those events, otherwise we’ll end up remaining strapped in our seats without meal services or toilets for the full duration of the flights. Or they will add padding everywhere, maybe, and we will travel encased in rubber foam.

The answer, while interesting, only tangentially adresses the (confused, off-topic, and borderline trolling) question. It will just serve to prevent automatic deletion. It might have been preferable not to post it or to create a separate Q&A on aviation.SE.
